# Help with a Problem Involving the Properties of Directional Derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question is about the properties of directional derivatives.
I came across this problem while reading [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/multivariable-calculus/multivariable-derivatives/modal/a/directional-derivative-introduction), a page on khan academy. It states that if $v^{\to}=\hat{\textbf{i}}+\hat{\textbf{j}}$, then $\nabla_{v^{\to}}f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, which I think implies that $\nabla_{v^{\to}}f=\nabla_{\hat{\textbf{i}}}f+\nabla_{\hat{\textbf{j}}}f$.

My question is, is it always true that $\nabla_{a^{\to}+b^{\to}}f=\nabla_{a^{\to}}f+\nabla_{b^{\to}}f$, and can you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, linearity of the directional derivative always holds (as long as your function is differentiable - *which is much stronger than having all directional derivatives*) and one can prove it: see [the answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2615324/linearity-of-the-directional-derivative).